# The function is not applied to the product category

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a problem, i can't find how to apply a function to a certain product category, i think that is all correct, so there is the code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 ); // Simple products

function jk_woocommerce_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
    if (is_product_category(29) ) {
        $args['input_value']    = 3;         // Starting value

        $args['max_value']                      = 999;      // Maximum value

        $args['min_value']                       = 3;         // Minimum value

        $args['step']                   = 3;   // Quantity steps
    }
    return $args;

}


// Variations

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'jk_woocommerce_available_variation' );

function jk_woocommerce_available_variation( $args ) {
    if ( is_product_category(29) ) {
        $args['max_qty'] = 999;                   // Maximum value (variations)

        $args['min_qty'] = 3;                   // Minimum value (variations)

    }
    return $args;
}
```

I hope that someone will help me.

Comment: is_product_category is not the proper condition. This is looking if  you are currenlty on category page with id 29. Read more here  - https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/ . You must check if current product is in this category. Use this if( has_term( 29, 'product_cat' ) ) {
 // do something if current product in the loop is in product category with ID 29
}